# iOS: Pushing a view controller with animation only works once

Tags: ios, pushviewcontroller

I am creating an iPhone client for one of my apps that has an API. I am using the GTMOAuth2 library for authentication. The library takes care of opening a web view for me with the correct url. However I have to push the view controller myself. Let me show you some code to make things more clear:

```
- (void)signInWithCatapult
{
    [self signOut];

    GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch *viewController;
    viewController = [[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch alloc] initWithAuthentication:[_account catapultAuthenticaiton]
                                                                 authorizationURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kCatapultAuthURL]
                                                                 keychainItemName:kCatapultKeychainItemName
                                                                         delegate:self
                                                                 finishedSelector:@selector(viewController:finishedWithAuth:error:)];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
}
```

I have a "plus"/"add" button that I add to the view dynamically and that points to that method:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(signInWithCatapult)];
```

When I press the "add" button, what is supposed to happen is to open the web view with an animation, and then add an account to the accounts instance variable which populates the table view. This works fine if I add one account, but as soon as I try to add a second account, the screen goes black and two errors appear in the console:

```
nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar

Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
```

The only way that I found to avoid this problem was to disable animations when pushing the view controller.

What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: You are popping a controller twice. Check your code and see where this happens.

Comment: I don't pop any controller, I just use `pushViewController:animated:` as shown in the code above. And why does it work once and not twice? Anyway, here is the link to the whole project, just in case you want to take a peak and see if you can spot something wrong: https://github.com/catapultcentral/Catapult-for-iOS/tree/develop

Comment: When I tap the + button, the app fails to connect to the server.

Comment: that's because the server is only local right now. The API is not live yet...

Comment: I won't be able to test your app then…

Comment: No you won't, unfortunately. But I managed to fix the problem, replacing the `pushViewController:animated` method by `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method. Now all I need to do is to find a way to add a cancel button to get out of the model once I'm in. Thanks a lot for trying to help though.

Comment: Looks like `GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch` needs a navigation bar. Also, read about Unwind segues to add a cancel button to the modal.

Answer (score 1):

Typical situations

1. You `push` or `pop` controllers inside `viewWillAppear:` or similar methods.
2. You override `viewWillAppear:` (or similar methods) but you are not calling `[super viewWillAppear:]`.
3. You are starting two animations at the same time, e.g. running an animated `pop` and then immediately running an animated `push`. The animations then collide. In this case, using `[UINavigationController setViewControllers:animated:]` must be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following for dismissing once you're in?

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the `nested pop animation can result in corrupted navigation bar` message when I was trying to pop a view controller before it had appeared. Override `viewDidAppear` to set a flag in your UIViewController subclass indicating that the view has appeared (remember to call `[super viewDidAppear]` as well). Test that flag before you pop the controller. If the view hasn't appeared yet, you may want to set *another* flag indicating that you need to immediately pop the view controller, from within `viewDidAppear`, as soon as it has appeared. Like so:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    bool didAppear, needToPop;
}
```

...and in the `@implementation`...

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    didAppear = YES;
    if (needToPop)
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)myCrucialBackgroundTask {
    // this task was presumably initiated when view was created or loaded....
    ...
    if (myTaskFailed) {  // o noes!
        if (didAppear)
            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        else
            needToPop = YES;
    }
}
```

The duplicated `popViewControllerAnimated` call is a bit ugly, but the only way I could get this to work in my currently-tired state.